# If $f: a \to b$ is representable and $g: b \to c$ is representable, then so is the composition $g\circ f$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, fibre-product

I'm studying from the [Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/001U).

They say the proof is omitted.  And they don't indicate the difficulty.  I've tried piecing together commuting squares etc, but have found nothing useable.

### Here's another attempt

$f : a \to b$ is representable iff for every other map $g: c \to b$ there is an object $d$ with arrows $p : d \to a, \ q : d \to c$ such that if $d'$ is another object with respective morphisms to $a, c$ such that $f \circ \alpha = g \circ \beta$, then there is a unique isomorphism $\gamma : d' \to d$ such that $p\circ \gamma = \alpha, \ q \circ \gamma = \beta$.

I added in the isomorphism part because it follows from Yoneda lemma.

So let prime notation indicate the other representable map $f' : b \to b'$ with $d', p', q', $ and any other map $g' : c' \to b'$.  For some reason, I want to say that since it's for any other map that we should let $g'= f' \circ f : a \to b'$. Which then in a way includes the composition we're after.

### Working on it.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the Stacks Project as opposed to some other resource for becoming familiar with category theory? I assume you are ultimately interested in stacks, but the Stacks Project doesn't consider itself an introductory text to algebraic stacks (though that was the original intent), let alone an introductory text to the topics covered in the preliminaries. The entire "Categories" section is only 87 pages and goes well beyond a typical introduction. This leaves little space for discussion, examples, intuition, or exercises.

Comment: As for the problem, if you have a rectangle consisting of two pullback squares (what the Stacks Project calls "cartesian squares"), then the whole rectangle is a pullback square. This is what needs to be proven.

Comment: @DerekElkins I've been looking at many books.  The Stacks Project, the way it's organized and its pace is what attracts me.  I use other sources too, but I've never gotten to Yoneda lemma until I started studying on Stacks.  Now I can prove Yoneda!

Comment: @DerekElkins okay, thank you.  I'll look into pullbacks.  Please no one post the answer.

Comment: "Pullback" is just another word for "fibred product". I meant to state that.

Comment: @FruitfulApproach I see that you have created ([tag:fibre-product]) tag. It might be useful to create also [tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/fibre-product/info). It might help other users to use the tag correctly. Another reason is that the tags used on only one question are [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after certain time [unless they have tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127700). And the same goes for the other two tags you [created recently](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2017/5/30).

Comment: @MartinSleziak thank you

Comment: Incidentally, I think the intuition being invoked here is that $g : c \to b$ represents something like an "object over $b$ or an "element of $b$". The arrow $p : d \to a$ is correspondingly viewed as the "inverse image" of $g$, which we might write as $f^{-1}(g)$ or $f^*(g)$, particularly when we are viewing it as representing an "object over $a$" or "element of $a$".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @DerekElkins comments.  The [Pullback article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)#Properties) on wikipedia, has a nice picture of the two pasted together commuting squares.

So I want to prove the isomorphism $(a \times_b c) \times_c d \simeq a \times_b d$ where $a \times_b c$ is the fibre product, also known as a pullback.

Let $a \times_b c$ together with $a \xrightarrow{f} b, \ c \xrightarrow{g} b$ be one pullback with projections $p: \to a, \ q :\to c$.

In other words let one pullback square be:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
a\times_b c @>{q}>> a \\
@V{p}VV @VV{f}V \\
c  @>{g}>>b
\end{CD}
$$

Now my mistake was to try and attach the second square on the right, but it actually fits nicely on the left.

So let $(a \times_b c) \times_c d$ be the next fiber product with $g' = p$ by choice since we have $h : d \to c$ is representable iff $\forall \ g': a\times_b c \to c$ there is a fiber product between $h$ and $g'$.  So the two squares together become:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(a\times_b c)\times_c d @>{q'}>> a\times_b c @>{q}>> a \\
@V{p'}VV @V{p}VV @VV{f}V \\
d @>{h}>> c  @>{g}>> b
\end{CD}
$$

Thus, letting $e = (a \times_b c) \times_c d$ we should have a pullback rectangle.  That is, a fiber product between $gh$ and $f$.  We need to show that for any $e'\xrightarrow{\alpha'} d, \ e' \xrightarrow{\beta'} b$ such that $gh \circ \alpha' = f \circ \beta'$ there exists a pullback morphism $e' \xrightarrow{u'} e$ such that $p'\circ u' = \alpha'$ and $qq'\circ u' = \beta'$.

Well, let $\alpha = h \circ \alpha', \ \beta = \beta'$ then $\alpha, \beta$ are the two corresponding pullback morphisms (in the definition) for the square on the right.  So that there is a unique morphism $e'\xrightarrow{u} a\times_b c$ such that $p\circ u' = \alpha$ and $q \circ u' = \beta$.  But then we can let $\beta'' = u'$ and we have $p\circ \beta'' = h \circ \alpha '$ already so that there must exist a unique morphism $e' \xrightarrow{u''} e$ such that $p'\circ u'' = \alpha'$ and $q'\circ u'' = \beta''$.  But then $qq'\circ u'' = q\circ\beta'' = q \circ u' = \beta$, which goes to the upper-right corner of the full rectangle by definition.

That completes the proof via diagram chasing. $\square$

---

Thus, we have that there exists a fiber product $a \times_b d$ or that the composition of representable maps $g\circ h$ is also representable.